# Twisted port 80 requiring manual port 80 and not working

Tags: python-3.x, http, ssl, https, twisted

Throws no errors, yet silently there are problems.

When I run the usual server with python

```
python -m http.server 80
```

It works fine and I may access the server with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, but when I try running a secure twisted server with

```
twistd -no web --path=. --https=80 --certificate=../cert.pem --privkey=../key.pem
```

and try to access via a browser with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` my browser can't connect and I must use `https://localhost:80` or `https://127.0.0.1:80` to connect.

Here's the server startup output:

```
twistd -no web --path=. --https=80 --certificate=../cert.pem --privkey=../key.pem
2016-11-14T17:41:47+1100 [twisted.application.app.AppLogger#info] twistd 16.5.0 (c:\python35\python.exe 3.5.0) starting up.
2016-11-14T17:41:47+1100 [twisted.application.app.AppLogger#info] reactor class: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.
2016-11-14T17:41:47+1100 [-] Site (TLS) starting on 80
2016-11-14T17:41:47+1100 [twisted.web.server.Site#info] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x03028E50>
2016-11-14T17:41:47+1100 [-] Site starting on 8080
```

But I also can't get the normal http to server on port 80.

Here is my question now.

1) How can I allow a client to connect without the trailing `:80`?

Comment: `https://localhost:80/` * correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS defaults to port 443, whereas HTTP defaults to port 80. The two are different protocols. Note that your HTTP server is running on 8080 as per the shown output. Since you are using a non-standard port for HTTPS, you have to specify the port explicitly.

Comment: Now I feel really like a dumb.

Comment: Also just for the information the launch options can be `--port X` for HTTP port and `--htttps X` for HTTPS port.